# MVVM without 'standard model'

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Almost every tutorial explains MVVM in WPF in the same manner: We have some entity (Person, Student, Car etc) - we create a Model class for it that will only carry data (it might also implement INotifyPropertyChange, IDataErrorInfo and whatnot - doesn't matter now), then we create a View-Model for that class, that will query and/or save our entity/ies somewhere (most likely via Commands) - our View will bind to the View-Model and voilà.

Let's say we have an application that won't, for a difference, work with querying/saving entities. Let's say it should contain a button that when clicked will download an .exe file (in a background thread) and will launch it. I'm curious, how would you approach this (architecture-wise) - would you actually create a folder/class named 'Model' for that program? What would it contain? How I see it, I'd have two abstractions - one for downloading a file and one for launching it. I'd inject them to View-Model and call their methods (via Command) and that's it. Or should it be a Model class that contains these abstractions? I know this question might seem strange, but it's something that's been bothering me for some time.

Btw, I realise the title of this post doesn't tell much - I didn't have a better idea for it, if someone does - feel free to change it.

Comment: MVVM is only really relevant in complex applications with business logic you have to test rigorously.  For a simple application just throw it in the codebehind and move on.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you provide, how the MVVM model will be setup is as follows. Let us assume that you want to download some data and show it in a `DataGrid` which is part of your view. In the `View` you add your `DataGrid` and `Button`, bind your button click to the `ViewModel` via a command. Bind your `DataGrid` via `ItemSource` to some `ObservableCollection<T>` in the view model (the view model must implement `INotifyPropertyChange`). Now, when the user clicks the button the command will fire and you can go and fill you `ObservableCollection<T>` with data via the download, the downloaded data which is bound to the UI will automatically display...

I hope this helps.